# How to round floating point error in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to round floating point error in javascript?

Comment: use toFixed() Method, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: …so the error is rounder? Sorry, couldn't resist. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

use toFixed to round it then convert it back to a number

```
var num = 1.00000000000000002341;
alert(+num.toFixed(10));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dz7c/)**

Answer (score 0):

To round towards 0 to get a 32 bit signed integer, use `x | 0`.

There's also the `Math.round` function which rounds towards the closest integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Math.round(number * 1E6) / 1E6` to round up to 6 decimal places.